# Gulp CSS syntax errors fail silently using gulp-concat and gulp-plumber

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-concat

I am using gulp-concat and the sourcemap functionality for some CSS files. I am using plumber to catch any syntax errors in the source files. My problem is plumber doesn't warn me of errors when using gulp-concat. If I switch to gulp-concat-css error handling works fine, but then I lose sourcemap functionality. My code is below:

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/*.css')    
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())    
    .pipe(concat('styles.css'))         
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('src/*.css', ['styles'])
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've used the errorHandler option that plumber provides. It would look something like this in your code:

```
var onError = function (err) {
  console.log(err);
};

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/*.css')    
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: onError
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())    
    .pipe(concat('styles.css'))         
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});
```

Hope it helps.